# React Native 0.71.7 Cmake-reanimated bug

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For some reason I am not able to 'npm run android' anymore on React native version 0.71.7.
The only thing I changed is that I did installed 'react-native-dotenv' to secure API keys and right after commit the issue comes.

The error code is CXX1405, it also warns to update Cmake version to 3.19.

I try to downgrade from react-native-reanimated: "^3.0.2" to @2.14.4 and everything works.
But before it was working with the @3.0.2. I cannot understand whats wrong now.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me, even if I try to upgrade the Cmake to 19+ and NDK to 24+ from the android studio it doesn't work

Comment: I did reinstalled Android Studio, updated Node to LTS, tried also with other Cmake versions and nothing worked. So, curently I just using older react-native-reanimated version (2.14.4)

Comment: actually 2.17.0 reanimated could be more helpful, try updating